# Why I can't use same Directory config for httpd.conf on CentOS and on FreeBSD?

Tags: apache-httpd, freebsd

I'm migrating product from CentOS 6 to FreeBSD 10.3, and put my_product.conf into apache24/Includes. One strange thing, on CentOS it works with:

```
<Directory "/usr/local/share/my_product">
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

but doesn't work on FreeBSD. Instead, it works with:

```
<Directory "/usr/local/share/sso_portal">
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Why? And where I can find comprehensive information about all differences, milestones, etc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are missing details in your question with versions of apache webserver you use. So I assume that it's 2.2 (default on CentOS 6) and 2.4 (not sure if default on FreeBSD). If it is true, than there are differences in configuration of apache. See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html for more details. It's not problem of CentOS nor FreeBSD.

Comment: Great! You're a telepath and master :)